# How to create a new browser window in Electron Angular app with a given component as stat screen

Tags: html, angular, electron

I have an existing Electron Angular app all running fine.
I want to create a new window on a button click and have that window use a given Angular component for it's initial UI content.

So I make a new component like so:

ng generate component TrivialComponent

Now, in my electron app I make sure that at top of app.module.ts I have:

```
import { TrivialComponent } from './trivial.component';
```

and also that it is added to declarations like so:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TrivialComponent,
```

now, on my button click event I add:

```
var w = new BrowserWindow({
                title: "My Title",
                minWidth: 800,
                minHeight: 600,
                frame: true,
                resizable: true,
                transparent: false,
                closable: true,
                show: false,
                webPreferences: {
                  nodeIntegration: true,
                  contextIsolation: false,
                  allowRunningInsecureContent: true,
                  enableRemoteModule: true
                } as Electron.WebPreferences
              });

              w.show();

                w.loadFile("dist/index2.html");
```

and the body of index2.html is:

```
<body class="igx-typography">
  <app-trivial></app-trivial>
</body>
```

When I run this I get a new empty window, but content is blank rather then the html of my new component, which is:

```
<p>Trivial component works!</p>
```

Would anyone know what I am missing?